# Carto-CSS/ Mapnik XML Text background color

Tags: mapnik, cartocss

I want to add a background color to my labels. How do I do that with Carto-CSS in Tilemill or with Mapnik?

Carto-CSS

```
#marker_labels {
  text-name: "[name]";
  text-face-name:@sans;
  text-size: 20;
  text-fill: #FFFFFF;
  text-allow-overlap: true,
}
```

Mapnik XML

```
<TextSymbolizer face-name="Air Soft Cond Heavy" size="20" fill="#ffffff" allow-overlap="true" ><![CDATA[[name]]]></TextSymbolizer>
```

Here is a example on how the label should look like (ignore the line to the label):[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand question correctly you should use Carto-CSS 'text-halo' operator:

```
text-halo-radius:
text-halo-fill:
```

If you need background as a rectangular behind the text, you should use 'shield' operators.

Comment: Yes, I want to use a rectangular background behind the text. That's why halo will not work. I added a sample image to my question to clarify. If I understand shield right, I always have to use a image for it, right?

Comment: Yes, you use 'shield-file' operator to determine your image as a background, but in this case, your background will have a fix size..

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample code for putting up background with CSS :

/* CSS by GenerateCSS.com */ background-color: #dfdff2; background-image:url(""); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-position: center center;

I used a CSS generator with this one: http://www.generatecss.com/css/background/

Comment: I am trying to do this with Tilemill. Tilemill uses Carto-CSS, which is different than CSS. As far as I know Carto-CSS does not have a background syntax.